# Create a command/alias in zsh that is only available when in a specific directory

Tags: terminal, zsh

Is it possible to create a command that is only available when in a current directory or any of it's subdirectories. For example, let's say I want to create a command/alias called `cdtheme` and I have the following directory structure

```
~/code

# PROJECTNAME and THEMENAME can be anything the rest of the structure will stay the same
~/code/PROJECTNAME/web/themes/THEMENAME

~/code/projectA/web/themes/theme1
~/code/projectB/web/themes/theme2
~/code/xyzproject/web/themes/randomthemename
```

Running `cdtheme` in the following directories would result in the following

```
~/code # error

~/code/projectA # cd to theme1
~/code/projectA/web # cd to theme1

~/code/projectB # cd to theme2

~/code/xyzproject # cd to randomthemename
```

`cdtheme` is just an example I would like to add more commands such as `cdproject`.
My initial thought was to be able to add a file into a directory e.g `projectB/.zshrc` where I could define the custom command/alias/variables and have this picked up automatically.

Edit: Clarity and add context

Comment: By move, do you mean move a file or change drectory?

Comment: It's also unclear where exactly you want to move to - `projectB` or `projectB/web/themes...`

Comment: You can replace `cd` with a `cd` function in your `~/.bashrc` that does a `builtin cd "$@"` , then looks around an sets up the alias OR unaliases it. Read `man bash`

Comment: I've updated my question to make it clearer what I'm looking to achieve

Answer (score 2):

You can define and undefine aliases or functions in a [`chpwd` hook](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions).

```
function set_theme_dir {
  case $PWD/ in
    ~/code/projectA/) alias cdtheme='cd ~/code/projectA/web/themes/theme1';;
    ~/code/projectB/) alias cdtheme='cd ~/code/projectB/web/themes/theme2';;
    *) unalias cdtheme;;
  esac
}
chpwd_functions+=(set_theme_dir)
```

But given your requirements I think it makes more sense for `cdtheme` to be always defined and to analyse the current directory when it runs.

```
function cdtheme {
  case $PWD/ in
    ~/code/projectA/) cd ~/code/projectA/web/themes/theme1;;
    ~/code/projectB/) cd ~/code/projectB/web/themes/theme2;;
    *) echo "Error: not inside a project tree" >&2; return 2;;
  esac
}
```

It's not clear whether theme directories are hard-coded or can be determined from the project, or how to tell what the project directory is. Here's an implementation of `cdtheme` that assumes that each project is its own Git worktree and that you want the first theme in lexicographic order.

```
function cdtheme {
  emulate -L zsh
  setopt err_return
  local root
  root=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
  cd $root/web/themes/theme*([1])
}
```

Comment: or `case $PWD/ in (~/dir/*)...` to avoid the `(|/*)`.